# Blower motor fails directly after maintenance check and AC float switch install

Tags: maintenance, damage, blower, motor

I had a maintenance check on my Carrier HVAC and also had a float switch installed.  All checked out fine and I turned off the AC til the next day because it was cold in the house.  The next day it stopped working properly, intermittently. The guy came back and said he hadn't connected the electric securely after float switch install.  I thought it would be fixed, but my AC continued to work intermittently and had never done that before.   The company sent another guy out, they say the blower motor needs replacement but I should replace the whole AC because it's a $1500 OEM blower motor replacement (Model: FB4CNF036T00ACAA)

Could the float switch install or maintenance check have caused this?  I'd never had a problem with the AC before, and upon their maintenance check where everything checked out fine, the blower motor just happened to fail immediately after?

How can I prove that they caused this, if that is likely?
Thank you!

Comment: Possible it just happen afterwards, but a bit weird.  For 1500 motor or new ac, I would want a different company/inspector to check.  The age of the unit might be important also.  Maintenance checks are usually a look see and check on fluid levels, not a complete tear down to look for problems/wear.

Comment: Yes it's an older system, but had always worked perfectly.  I'm wondering if I hire someone to check, would it be detectable whether the prior inspector did something to cause this?  He could have knocked a fuse loose and nobody can prove that...from what I've researched, it looks like that might have happened

Comment: A different guy might see something like a weak 20$ capacitor than a 1500 replacement motor, or say the motor is shot also.  Most simple maintenance should not damage stuff.  It is usually just a cleaning and minor adjustments.

Comment: This blower motor type (OEM) cannot be opened up and fixed, such as replace a capacitor, because it's like a mini computer and the entire thing is ruined if it's opened up, apparently.  So if stuff inside it was knocked loose, there is no way to know.  I'm just concerned that the guy damaged/made a wrong electrical connection, because he was new, very nice guy, but he had connected the electrical component incorrectly for the float switch.  The timing --first time the AC was turned on less than 24 hours after the maintenance check...

Comment: If it was the first time it was turned on for the season, the idea that the motor would malfunction isn't as unusual. I don't really understand how "looking" at the system and hooking up a float switch could fry the blower motor tho. And a $1500 blower motor sounds kind of excessive. I'd call someone else out to take a look and test the components, float switch wiring, etc.

Comment: $1500 includes removal and installation.  But I wouldn't use this company again, although they're really nice and I think honest, I just wonder whether this new guy could've messed something up without knowing, and whether it's worth a check.  I'm in TX so the AC had already been used plenty, no problems.  Are there any AC experts who can tell me whether it's worth another $200 visit to have this assessed?  Thanks!  ...also, if anyone knows a place to buy a good 2.5 Ton 15.2 SEER2 for a great price? Cuz it looks like I may need to do that ASAP :(